# HTTP GET more efficient that POST for web service?

Tags: post, service, get

I have been told that a POST in some way does a double send to the server but GET does not.  It sounds a bit crazy to me though.

Basically I'm working on a web project where each client calls a web service every 2 seconds from many countries and possible bad internet connections.  So we want to make the calls and responses as tiny as possible between JavaScript and ASP.Net.

Security is not a problem and basically the poll is just returning data.  Login is required to use it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> I have been told that a POST in some way does a double send to the server but GET dose not. It sounds a bit crazy to me though.

You have been told wrong. The only difference is that POST allows for sending larger amount of data to the server and of course the more data you send the slower it will be. But if you send the same amount of data there won't be any difference in terms of performance between a GET and POST request.

One important thing to note as well is that if you are calling this service from javascript GET requests might be cached by the client browser. So for example if you are calling the same url over and over again using an AJAX GET request you might get cached values and the server never hit. To workaround this issue you could append a random number in the query string which has no meaning for the server but which *changes* the url and avoids it being cached.

Comment: Astute readers will recognize using the randomized URL as being longer, and hence, less efficient than POST would be in this situation.

Comment: I found it to be less efficient using GET in fact. I think because the characters had to be encoded the request was slightly larger.  Never heard of this double server hit before though.

Answer (score 0):

When sending thru ajax post, some developers may have inited post on form submit and a submit button click. Later when they press the send button, both actions get fired. This might be the experience that people who have told you double sending thing experienced.

Note: This double sending of POST is totally a developer's fault. HTTP POST method has nothing to do with it.